# A question about the particular solution of a Non linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that if you have a non homogeneous **linear** ordinary differential equation, then you first find a solution to the homogenous case and then add up with a particular solution to get the general solution for the original non homogeneous ODE.

But my question is if the ODE is non linear, would the same theory be applied?

Comment: Would there be a homogeneous case of a non-linear ODE such as $y'y=x$?. Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a linear differential equation of order n
$$k_n\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+k_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+...+k_{1}\frac{dy}{dx}+k_0 y=f(x)$$
The homogeneous case would be
$$k_n\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+k_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+...+k_{1}\frac{dy}{dx}+k_0 y=0$$
we find the characteristic polynomial be assuming that y is an exponential function of $y=c_1e^{\lambda_1}+c_2e^{\lambda_2}+...+c_ne^{\lambda_n}$ such that $c_1, c_2,...c_n \in {\rm I\!R}$. This is exclusive to linear ODEs to solve for

Now if we have a non-linear ODE for example

$$y''y + y'y+xy=0$$
If you assumed $f(x)$ to be a solution of the ODE, the homogeneous case would state that a function times any constant $y=cf(x)$ would also be a solution. Plug this into the ODE
$$c^2f(x)''f(x) + c^2f'(x)f(x)+cxf(x)=0$$
We cannot factor out the constant so $cf(x) $ would not be a solution but $f(x)$ would

I hope this helps